# How is a DOM tree constructed?

Tags: dom, xml-parsing, tree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "validator.dtd">

<people>
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
        <course>Computer Technology</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>

    <student>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <course>Industrial Electronics</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>
</people>
```

This is my XML document. I have made a tree representation of this.
[image]

Is this tree representation correct or is it wrong ?

Comment: Well, Student "Foo" is not in your diagram, so it doesn't seem completely correct.

Comment: @Henrik I know, I skipped that for space constraints

Comment: You forgot the empty text nodes before and after each child node. Why don't you construct the DOM then print it out?

Comment: @bmorris591 if you could make an answer pointing out everything that is wrong and right with this then it would be appreciated

Comment: @LittleChild: Ok. Then it would be helpful if you could define what 'correct' means in this case.

Comment: @Henrik I am unsure as to whether the text nodes should be one level up. I mean, while traversing the tree, is this the structure I will be dealing with ? or is it wrong ?

Comment: @LittleChild: Still a little bit unsure about what you are asking. I opened the XML document in Chrome. This XPath expression (use the JavaScript console) `$x("//people/student/name/text()")` provides the output `["John", "Foo"]`. Does that help you in any way whatsoever? :)

Comment: @Henrik ahhhh... so `John` will be a child of `name` and not on the same level as name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a pretty good idea by just printing a DOM tree:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    final String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"
            + "<people>"
            + "    <!-- a comment -->"
            + "    <student>"
            + "        <name>John</name>"
            + "        <!-- a comment -->"
            + "        <course>Computer Technology</course>"
            + "        <semester>6</semester>"
            + "        <scheme>E</scheme>"
            + "    </student>"
            + ""
            + "    <student>"
            + "        <name>Foo</name>"
            + "        <course>Industrial Electronics</course>"
            + "        <semester>6</semester>"
            + "        <scheme>E</scheme>"
            + "    </student>"
            + "</people>";
    final Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    printNodes(document.getDocumentElement(), 0);
}

private static void printNodes(final Node node, final int depth) {
    final StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
        prefix.append("\t");
    }
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        System.out.println(prefix.toString() + "Going into " + node.getNodeName());
        final NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
            printNodes(nodeList.item(i), depth + 1);
        }
    } else if (node.getNodeType() == Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
        System.out.println(prefix.toString() + "Comment node: \"" + node.getTextContent() + "\"");
    } else {
        System.out.println(prefix.toString() + "Text node: \"" + node.getTextContent() + "\"");
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Going into people
    Text node: "    "
    Comment node: " a comment "
    Text node: "    "
    Going into student
        Text node: "        "
        Going into name
            Text node: "John"
        Text node: "        "
        Comment node: " a comment "
        Text node: "        "
        Going into course
            Text node: "Computer Technology"
        Text node: "        "
        Going into semester
            Text node: "6"
        Text node: "        "
        Going into scheme
            Text node: "E"
        Text node: "    "
    Text node: "    "
    Going into student
        Text node: "        "
        Going into name
            Text node: "Foo"
        Text node: "        "
        Going into course
            Text node: "Industrial Electronics"
        Text node: "        "
        Going into semester
            Text node: "6"
        Text node: "        "
        Going into scheme
            Text node: "E"
        Text node: "    "
```

As you can see there are text nodes everywhere, in between the visible nodes. This is because you could, in theory, have text *around* a child node - for example

```
<student>
    some random text
    <course>Computer</course>
    some more text
</student>
```

So the DOM tree needs to take this into account. If the XML was not pretty-printed but just a single line then the next nodes would be empty rather than full of whitespace.

Fiddle around with the document and see what impact it has on the output.

Comment: OK, so `John` is a `Text` node which is a child of `name` :) right ?

Comment: Applies same for comments too ? I mean will `<!-- this is a comment -->` will have a `Comment` node with a `Text` node as a child ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild updated my answer. A comment is actually a special type of text node. Might be worth taking a look at the [`Node` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)

Comment: How do I avoid printing the `some random text` ?

Comment: You have to know what you are parsing, you can't just blindly iterate. If you use the tests that are in my code (`node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE`) you can skip text nodes where you don't expect them.